# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/firebase_app.js?v=a3e48a6a' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: firebase, svelte, vite

I am using Svelte with Vite and just installed firebase using `npm i firebase`. Simply writing the following code:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
```

yields the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/firebase_app.js?v=a3e48a6a' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

I tried the following:

1. Installing and uninstalling different versions of firebase.
2. Trying different ways to import firebase